# Android: Platform tools missing in the android_sdk_r16 zip package

Tags: android

The platform tools component is missing in the latest android sdk package.

We can download it from the `SDKManager.exe` but is there any location where I can download the SDK package with platform tools directly.

Thanks.

AjS

Answer (score 1):

sdk package is a starter kit, SDK Manager inside eclipse is the only way you can get platforms  .

Answer (score 0):

During first run it is expected to download it for new sdk. Go to AVD and download it